# Passing information from MySQL to Android via PHP - Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException: lock == null

Tags: java, php, android, mysql

I am new to Android and I am trying to make am simple APP the access a server and read a table in a database. I used this example http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/ and tried to make some adaptations.

There has been many errors that I was able to solve searching here, but on this case I haven´t been luck so far.

As suggest, I did some debbuging and the app stops working when to line 108

```
    try{
        //Verificando a TAG Sucesso
        int sucess = json.getInt(TAG_SUCESSO);
```

For the varibles, just befor that, json appears as null.

As it seens I am having trouble to get the response from my PHP code (it shows the right array and executed) to the app.

Here is the Logcat error

```
12-22 11:50:35.609    1273-1293/br.com.agenciaeisberg.qm E/Buffer Error﹕ Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException: lock == null
12-22 11:50:35.859    1273-1293/br.com.agenciaeisberg.qm E/JSON Parser﹕ Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of
12-22 11:50:35.859    1273-1293/br.com.agenciaeisberg.qm W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=12: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb2a24ba8)
12-22 11:50:36.799    1273-1293/br.com.agenciaeisberg.qm E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
    Process: br.com.agenciaeisberg.qm, PID: 1273
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
            at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at br.com.agenciaeisberg.qm.ListagemHospitaisActivity$LoadListagemHospitais.doInBackground(ListagemHospitaisActivity.java:104)
            at br.com.agenciaeisberg.qm.ListagemHospitaisActivity$LoadListagemHospitais.doInBackground(ListagemHospitaisActivity.java:76)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
12-22 11:50:38.039    1273-1273/br.com.agenciaeisberg.qm W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
12-22 11:50:39.259    1273-1273/br.com.agenciaeisberg.qm E/WindowManager﹕ android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity br.com.agenciaeisberg.qm.ListagemHospitaisActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{b2ce6d30 V.E..... R......D 0,0-320,96} that was originally added here
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:348)
            at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:248)
            at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
            at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:286)
            at br.com.agenciaeisberg.qm.ListagemHospitaisActivity$LoadListagemHospitais.onPreExecute(ListagemHospitaisActivity.java:88)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:587)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:535)
            at br.com.agenciaeisberg.qm.ListagemHospitaisActivity.onCreate(ListagemHospitaisActivity.java:59)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is the Activity

```
package br.com.agenciaeisberg.qm;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ListagemHospitaisActivity extends ListActivity {

    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // Creating JSON Parser object
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> ListaHospitais;

    //url para lista hospitais
    private static String url_lista_hospitais = "http://127.0.0.1/QM/lista_hospitais.php";

    //JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_HOSPITAIS = "hospitais";
    private static final String TAG_PID = "pid";
    private static final String TAG_NOME = "nome";
    private static final String TAG_SUCESSO = "sucesso";
    //private static final String TAG_LOTACAO = "lotacao";
    //private static final String TAG_DATA_LOTACAO = "data_lotacao";

    //hospitais JSONARRAY
    JSONArray hospitais = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.lista_hospitais);

        //Hashmap for ListView
        ListaHospitais = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

        // Carregando hospitais no backgroung
        new LoadListagemHospitais().execute();

        // Get ListView
        //ListView lv = getListView();

        //Selecionando um Hospital
        //Executa atividade Hospital
        //Criar código depois -> pesquisar linhas abaixo
        // on seleting single product
        // launching Edit Product Screen

    }

    /**
     * Background Async Task para carregar todos os hospitais através de um HTTP Request
     */

    class LoadListagemHospitais extends AsyncTask <String, String, String>{
        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */

         @Override
        protected void onPreExecute(){
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(ListagemHospitaisActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Aguarde, carregando Hospitais");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * Buscando os hospitais do URL
         * */

        protected String doInBackground (String... args) {
            //Criação dos parâmetros
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

            // Buscando o string JSON do URL
            JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_lista_hospitais,"GET", params);

            // Check your log cat for JSON reponse

            Log.d("Listagem Hospitais: ", json.toString());

            try{
                //Verificando a TAG Sucesso
                int sucess = json.getInt(TAG_SUCESSO);

                if (sucess == 1){
                    //existe hospital cadastrado

                    // Buscando Array dos hospitais
                    hospitais = json.getJSONArray(TAG_HOSPITAIS);

                    //loop por todos os Hospitais

                    for (int i = 0; i < hospitais.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = hospitais.getJSONObject(i);

                        // Armazenando as variáveis
                        String id = c.getString(TAG_PID);
                        String nome = c.getString(TAG_NOME);

                        // creando novo HashMap
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        // adicionando cada child node ao HashMap . key => value
                        map.put(TAG_PID, id);
                        map.put(TAG_NOME, nome);

                        // adicionando HashList à ArrayList
                        ListaHospitais.add(map);
                    }

                }else{

                    // no products found
                    // Launch Add New product Activity
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                            MainActivity.class);
                    // Closing all previous activities
                    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            }catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
             return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/

        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // Dismiss a caixa de dialogo depois de buscar todos os items
            pDialog.dismiss();

            // atualizando UI from Background Thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    /**
                     * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                     * */
                    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                            ListagemHospitaisActivity.this, ListaHospitais,
                            R.layout.lista_hospitais, new String[] { TAG_PID,
                            TAG_NOME},
                            new int[] { R.id.pid, R.id.nome });
                    // updating listview
                    setListAdapter(adapter);
                }
            });

        }


    }

}
```

Here is the JSONParser Class

```
package br.com.agenciaeisberg.qm;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.util.Log;


public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    // function get json from url
    // by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
    public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
                                      List<NameValuePair> params) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {

            // check for request method
            if(method == "POST"){
                // request method is POST
                // defaultHttpClient
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();

            }else if(method == "GET"){
                // request method is GET
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
            }

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
}
```

Here is the php Code

```
<?php

/*
 * O código a seguir lista todos os hospitais
 */


//array para Resposta JSON
$response = array();

require_once 'geral.inc.php';

// connecting to db

$con = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $senha, $banco);

// Listar todos os Hospitais
$result = mysqli_query($con, 'SELECT * FROM hospitais');

$response['hospitais'] = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    //array temporário
    $hospital = array ();
    $hospital['pid'] = $row['PID'];
    $hospital['nome'] = $row['NomeHospital'];
    $hospital['lotacao'] = $row['ultima_lotacao'];
    $hospital['data_lotacao'] = $row['d_h_ultima_lotacao'];

    // Exibe o resultado um a um da array
    array_push($response["hospitais"], $hospital);
}

$response["successo"] = 1;

// echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);

?>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: If I run the php in my local server, here is the result.

{"hospitais":[{"pid":"1","nome":"Madre Teresa","lotacao":"4","data_lotacao":"2014-12-15 14:04:00"},{"pid":"2","nome":"Lifecenter","lotacao":"3","data_lotacao":"2014-11-26 16:06:24"},{"pid":"3","nome":"Israeltia Albert Einstein","lotacao":"9","data_lotacao":null},{"pid":"4","nome":"Santa Julia","lotacao":"9","data_lotacao":null},{"pid":"5","nome":"Santa Clara","lotacao":"9","data_lotacao":null},{"pid":"6","nome":"Vera Cruz","lotacao":"3","data_lotacao":"2014-11-24 11:36:41"}},"successo":1}

Comment: I guess the problem is that you receive a empty response from the server and you try to parse an empty String.

Anyway, i recommend you 2 libraries to make easy the request and parsing. Retrofit for REST request and GSON from json parsing (retrofit uses gson)

Comment: When you dump this much code in your post, it gives the impression that you haven't taken some basic debugging steps to find out where the exception could possibly be happening to begin with. On what line is it occurring?

Comment: @tnw .... I did what you suggested and updated my post. I new to all this, including posting in Stackoverflow ... Thanks for the tip.

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at br.com.agenciaeisberg.qm.ListagemHospitaisActivity$LoadListagemHospitais.doInBackground(ListagemHospitaisActivity.java:104)`